# When does a function admit a Taylor development in 0?

Tags: taylor-expansion

I don't remember much about Taylor series, but in a theorem, I have that something is true if a the function admits a taylor development in x = 0.  Is that equivalent to saying that the function in x = 0 is finite?

I don't have to re-learn everything about Taylor series, I just want to be able to use this theorem for an application.  Thank you.

Comment: Assuming by *Taylor development* you mean *Taylor series* (rather than, say, some finite-order Taylor polynomial), the function must be smooth (infinitely differentiable) at $x = 0$---this is more or less immediate from the definition. I don't know what you mean by a "finite" function in this context.

Comment: I meant that the limit of the function when x is close to 0 is finite.  But this pretty much answers my question.  Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad it was useful.

Answer (score 1):

If a function is not $k$ times differentiable, then you won't be able to expand its Taylor series past the $(k-1)$th term. As long as you have derivatives you have finite expansions (with Lagrange remainders), though note that for real functions having infinitely many derivatives (smooth) does not imply that the infinite Taylor series converges to the function (analytic).

Comment: Minor correction: infinitely many derivatives (smooth) does not imply the Taylor series converges (no special term); the Taylor series converging does not imply that it converges to the function (analytic). $f(x)=\begin{cases} e^{-1/x^2} & x \neq 0 \\ 0 & x=0 \end{cases}$ is the standard example of the latter point.

Comment: Good point. I just assumed "converges" would be read as "converges to the function", but there is a difference and it should be made explicit. Fixed.